# Changing a variable without reloading the page

Tags: python, flask

I have a list of image names loaded with flask, which I am rendering to an html template, so that the page displays the image. The only way I can seem to alter the image list (ie. add an image to it) is to make a view which contains code to change the list, but in order to access the view you have to reload the whole page again. Is there any way I can alter the list with flask without having to reload the whole page?

Comment: ajax request with javascript?

Comment: yeah but I want specifically to change the image list, which is a python variable. I would use js but it's handier using glob with python so I can load images without needing to know their filenames.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Jakob Bowyer is absolutely correct - use ajax:

```
from flask import jsonify
from werkzeug.security import safe_join

@app.route("/gallery")
def gallery():
    images = get_images_from_dir("some/base/path/*.jpg")
    return render_template("gallery.html", images=images)


@app.route("/search/images", methods=["POST"])
def search_images():
    glob_path = request.form["image_query"]
    glob_path = safe_join("/some/base/path", glob_path)
    return jsonify(images=get_images_from_dir(glob_path))
```

Then in your template just hit the appropriate endpoint:

```
<!-- snip -->
<script>
// jQuery here - you can use anything you want :-)
$.post({
    url: "{{ url_for("search_images") }}",
    success: function(data) {
        console.log(data);
    },
    error: function() { console.log("Error", arguments); }
});
</script>
```